# Intellij 12 no longer honors maven resource filtering on GWT Run configuration

Tags: intellij-idea

I have the following in my pom.xml...

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Then the following in my properties files

```
#Workspace Location
rp.config.workspace=${rp.config.workspace}
```

This allows me to switch Maven profiles when building via maven and have the correct settings for that environment injected right into the build.  Intellij 10 and 11 both would honor this resource filtering mechanism when running a GWT/Jetty/Tomcat/etc type run configuration without having to specify the goal "process resources" is run first in Maven which is very slow.

Now with the new v12 of Intellij the properties like ${rp.config.workspace} are not subsituted for the correct values specified in the  tag of the selected Maven profile.

Anybody else run into this?

Comment: Please, attach sample project, I can't reproduce this.

Answer (score 1):

Submitted the bug to YouTrack, please [watch/vote there](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-96854).